# How can I set two buttons on the right side of an UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have made a standard Master-Detail application (with the Xcode template). I modified it, and now when I click one cell of the first table view the app shows another table view (which is the detail because is filtered by the clicked cell value).
In a standard table view I would have this situation on the UINavigationBar:

`Edit                        Table title                           + (for adding new items)`

I need the default back button of UINavigationBar too. Is it possible and allowed to do this? Graphically it would be like this:

`< Back                      Table title                           Edit  +`

Do you know any other layout to display 3 button (back - edit - add) plus title all in the top bar?

Sorry for not posting images, Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'd like to know if it is possible to do the things I'm asking with built-in back button and edit button (I mean those that the system puts automatically to the navigation bar).

Answer (score 6):

you need to setup array of right bar items to set up bar buttons right side...

Here is the code of 2 custom button to setup bar button items right side...you can use default button instead of this

```
UIButton *btnabout =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnabout.frame = CGRectMake(0,8,30,30);
[btnabout setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"about.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnabout addTarget:self action:@selector(callselector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *about = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnabout];
about.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


UIButton *btnsetting =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnsetting.frame = CGRectMake(0,8,30,30);
[btnsetting setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnsetting addTarget:self action:@selector(SettingData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *setting = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnsetting];
setting.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:setting, about, nil];
// --- or if you want left side ----
//  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:setting, about, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[/*array of UIBarButtonItem*/] animated:NO]
```

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/setRightBarButtonItems:animated:)

Answer (score 0):

to someone stuck with this problem in swift, here is the correct answer :

```
let barButton_array: [UIBarButtonItem] = [Button1, Button2]
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(barButton_array, animated: false)
```