# UINavigatiobar right barbutton item image not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am creating a custom right bar button item for UINavigation bar. Here is the code I am using,

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    UIButton *backPageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backPageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    [ backPageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backPageButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [backPageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backPageButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [container addSubview:backPageButton];
    UIButton *forwardPageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [forwardPageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 50, 30)];
    [ forwardPageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [forwardPageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(forwardButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    forwardPageButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [forwardPageButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [container addSubview:forwardPageButton];

    UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:container];

// set the nav bar's right button item
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

For some reason the button images are not visible. I added a background color to each button and can see that the buttons are actually added to navigation bar and also the click events are working fine. But button images are not visible.

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen on both the simulator and the device?

Comment: why don't you make custom bar buttons using barbutton array .like this ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612471/how-can-i-set-two-buttons-on-the-right-side-of-an-uinavigationbar/31612665#31612665

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course you've made a double check that images belong to your target?
2. To debug your views in runtime you could use small but very useful button in Xcode

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFdDL.png]

more about this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html