# How to add multiple bar buttons to navigation bar

Tags: ios, navigation, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

Initially i have created a dynamic view called 'mainView'.In that,i have added Navigation bar.After that, i Want to add 2 right bar buttons to the navigation bar.If i code like this,its shows view with navigation bar.but its not showing right bar button.

1.Is it possible to add navigation bar without navigation controller?

2.Why the right bar button is not showing?

```
 //mainView Creation
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
mainView.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:mainView];

//NavigationBar
UINavigationBar *NavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
NavigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[mainView addSubview:NavigationBar];

//rightbarView Creation
UIView *rightbarView = [[UIView alloc] init];
rightbarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

//powerCut Button
UIButton *powerCutbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 20, 50, 14.01)];
[rightbarView addSubview:powerCutbutton];
UIImage *powercutimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"powercut.jpg"];
[powerCutbutton setImage:powercutimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// addConnection button
UIButton *addConnectionbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 20, 50, 14.01)];
[rightbarView addSubview:addConnectionbutton];
UIImage *addimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];
[addConnectionbutton setImage:addimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Barbutton item
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightbarView];
//[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:powerCutbutton, addConnectionbutton, nil]];

// setting rightbar button item
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612471/how-can-i-set-two-buttons-on-the-right-side-of-an-uinavigationbar/31612665#31612665

Answer (score 1):

create an array of bar buttons. and setLeftBarButtonItems not setLeftBarButtonItem as :

```
UIBarButtonItem * barbtn1;
UIBarButtonItem * barbtn2;
UIBarButtonItem * barbtn3;

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[barbtn1,barbtn2,barbtn3]];
```

or

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[barbtn1,barbtn2,barbtn3]];
```

hope it will helpful for you