# how to decrease back button wdth

Tags: ios

[image]

I want to remove extra white space. I have tried all the links provided but there is no luck. Can anybody help me please.

Comment: are you used two barbuttonItems

Comment: which buttons you used? Fixed space or flexible space bar button?

Comment: try this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612471/how-can-i-set-two-buttons-on-the-right-side-of-an-uinavigationbar/31612665#31612665

Comment: Add a custom BarButtonItem with required height and width.

Comment: No one is default back button of ios. And other is menu left button is a bar button

Answer (score 0):

Without adding BarButtonItem you can not modify back button because that is  default when you push a ViewController.